# involved in or involving in

Tags: word-usage

I ran into a sentence containing *involved in* and I think in this sentence, the verb should be used in its active form but there are many sentences like this.

> The four-step process involved in the creation of the mural took a year to complete.

Can I change the phrase *the four-step process involved in...* into *the four-step process which was involved in...*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The four-step process <strike>which was</strike> involved in the creation of the mural took a year to complete.
>
> The boy <strike>who is</strike> talking to the teacher is my friend.

The relative pronoun + be verb can sometimes be omitted from relative clauses. Both ways are acceptable.

Regarding involving and involved in, it usually follows this pattern:

`bigger thing` involves `smaller thing`

`smaller thing` is involved in `bigger thing`

Let's use **John** and **traffic accident**. It's pretty clear that in a traffic accident there are usually many factors and sometimes many people so **traffic accident will be our big thing** and **John will be our small thing**.

> John was involved in the traffic accident.
>
> There was a traffic accident involving John.

Comment: Amazing. The two patterns that you mentioned are exactly what made me confused. Thanks for your great explanation.

Comment: I usually use square brackets as the [orthographic] convention to indicate that some text element such as *[which was]* could be included in order to help someone parse a construction. But perhaps that's because of my programming background. But maybe you've got more going for you with *strikethrough* (which I don't think works in SO comments, so I'm not even going to try! :) because in *linguistic* terms we normally say such elements have been "deleted". Whatever - I think this is an excellent answer on all fronts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To be honest I've been wavering between various notations. I (and many others here I imagine), also have a programming background and as such it would be much easier if there was an accepted standard. I have not yet found one.

Comment: You guys meant this: _The boy (who is) talking to the teacher is my friend_? I prefer _omitted_ to _deleted_ as I often see the former in linguistic books.

Comment: @HồQuangTrung We are discussing what types of notation (brackets, braces, parentheses, strikethrough, asterisks, slashes etc.) we should be using.